# Android: How can I get a view of another fragment after GCM push?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to update my list view once I receive GCM push notification.
Im updating the listView from the database (and not from the push itself), but when I'm trying to get the view, it give me null and crash (Tried "GetView, getActivity... findViewById).

any other suggestion how can I do it?

Here is small sample of my code:
[GCM Class]:

```
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        if(myDbHelper.checkDataBase()) {
            DbServer gsh = new DbServer(getApplicationContext(),"getSQLiteHistory");
            //This might be an issue:
            gsh.setListener(new AlertsList());
            gsh.mContext=getApplicationContext();
            gsh.execute();
        }
```

[DataBaseHelper Class]

```
...
   //publish the list via listener
        mListener.finishRefresh(rowItems);
```

Listener:

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted{
    void finishRefresh(List<RowItem> rowItems);
}
```

[AlertList Class (contains "finishRefresh" function)]

```
listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list); //This is null
```

Anyone can point where can I get the View to update it after the GCM?

Thanks in advance!

Eran.

Comment: here is the crash error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getView() was null since GCM started this proccess (service).
what I did, I seperated "finishRefresh" function, to a new function once it came from the CGM class, then got the view from inflater, and only then I had the right view (not nulled)

Comment: @gvsharma what do you mean by get this? once I got the view from inflater: View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.alerts_list, null); everything works :)